# MS Word terminate wildcard in advanced search

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, search, wildcards

Is there a way to termiante the wilcard in the search, when I want to search for example for two words?

Let's say I have the following words

```
awesome mouse
awful albatros
awesome albatros
awful mouse
```

Now I'm trying to find specifically the combination of

```
aw* alba*
```

so my expected matches would be `awful albatros` and `awesome albatros` as two separate results

> (obviously in the example `?` would be more sufficient for wildcard, but I'm trying to use the wildcard for a search in foreign language where the endings of the word can have different length depending on the noun). So please, stick with the `*` wildcard

I tried all sort of things, including begin of word search and nested expressions, but I keep getting false matches, because the wildcard character `*` keeps interpreting everything as a  match afterwards and does not terminate the word.

This is the closest I could get to making sense of it -

```
<(aw)*{1,}\ (alba)*
```

Issue is, **the first `*` accepts everything after it and eats it up, when I in fact want to terminate it after a first space and then begin searching for second word (`alba*`)**

[image]

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `*` use group, e.g.:

`<aw[a-z]{1,} alba[a-z]{1,}>`

- you might need to include special characters in your group if your language contains them
- space isn't a special character, doesn't need to be escaped
- don't need to use brackets around strings, you might want to include the whole expression in one set of brackets (if you want to replace it for example)
- < and > matches beginning and end of word respective.

Further reading : https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm#adv

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention whether the words appear in the same line or in new paragraph, I am assuming both situations here.

**If they appear in the same line:**

[image]

*(The words appear in the same line and are separated by a space)*

In order to find that particular pattern of words, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to go to 'Find' menu. In **"Find what:"** type `[space](aw)*{1,}\ (alba)*` (where [space] refers to one stroke of space bar) and 'check' the 'Use Wildcards'.

Click **Find next**. You will have that particular pattern selected in your document:

[image]

*(Note that this search will also select the preceding space before the two words as shown above. So if you want to replace the above text with some other text keeping the same format, do not forget to add a space before the beginning of the replacement word; e.g. `Replace with`: `[space]SomeReplacementText`)*

**If they appear in different paragraphs or after a carriage return (as shown):**

[image]

In this case, in the `Find what:` enter this: `^13(aw)*{1,}\ (alba)*` and hit 'Find Next'. This will fetch you the desired result:

[image]

*(But remember that the above search keyword selects a preceding carriage return as shown above. So if you want to replace the above text with some other text keeping the format same do not forget to add a carriage return (`^13`) before the beginning of the replacement word; e.g. `Replace with`: `^13SomeReplacementText`)*

If you've those words in both the formats (i.e. in the same line as well as in new paragraphs), you've to do both steps one by one.

I hope this helps. Tell me how it does :)

Comment: `[space](aw)*{1,}\ (alba)*` this is essentially the same as the expression in the question

Comment: Yes, perhaps. But this does the work for the problem 
of OP quite well and it is all that matters. There can be many ways to solve one problem, that doesn't mean one working slightly differently deserve a downvote.